# MongoDB, How can I update an embedded doc in a set or insert one if it doesn't exist?

Tags: mongodb

How can I update an embedded document in a set or insert one if it doesn't exist in **single query**?
Say I have a document like below. And 'records' is a set of embedded documents.

```
{
    id: "1",
    records: [
        {userId:"5", userData: "..."},
        {userId:"12", userData: "..."},
        {userId:"27", userData: "..."}
    ]
}
```

I know how to insert or update 'records' in separate queries. But can I combine these queries so that it works similarly to MySQL's ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE? I want to avoid executing another query just to find out if an embedded document exists.

```
db.myCollection.update(
    {id:"1", records.userId:"12"},
    {records.$.userData:{"... new data ..."}}
);

db.myCollection.update(
    {id:"1"},
    {records:
        {$push:
            {userId: "33", userData: {"... new data ..."}}
        }
    }
);
```

Thanks

Comment: Well I did have an answer, but Stack Overflow decided on converting it to a comment.

Comment: Hi Na.z.Camp, do you still have a link to this 'comment' that you are referring to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10277174

Comment: Thank JohnnyHK, I have also considered structuring the 'records' as an object. However this incurs the index issue the original questioner mentioned. And that won't be suitable for the type of data stored in 'records'.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Upsert

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%7B%7Bupserts%7D%7D

Comment: Hi SCB, as far as I know upsert doesn't apply to **embedded** document. Please note I only want to modify main document's 'records' set.

Comment: Could you do it using a combination of the /*upsert*/ true on the update command and using the positional operator $?

Comment: @SCB, the MongoDB docs say "Do not use the positional operator $ with upsert operations because inserts will use the $ as a field name in the inserted document."   See here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/