# MongoDB. How to update json property inside an array

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm using the Mean stack. I'm uncomfortably new to this and have got myself in a pickle. I've seen examples of updating records using set or push but because I'm trying to update one json object within a json object within an array of json objects I'm having trouble.

Consider the following Schema

```
token: {
    type: String,
    required: "FB access token required."
},
fbId: {
    type: String,
    required: "FB id required.",
    unique: true
},
accounts: {
    type: Array,
    default: []
}
```

My accounts array consists of json objects, each of which look like this:

```
{
   "name": "some name",
   "credentials": {
       "username": "some username",
       "password": "some password"
}
```

I'm trying to update accounts each time the user adds a new one. So in this case I can use $push just fine. But I don't want duplicate names, and $push fails here.  So I tried using $set, but $set isn't inserting objects with new names into accounts. So I tried using upsert:true with $set, but now I'm getting duplicate errors.

Here is an example where I try to index name in accounts. I'm assuming I'm screwing up my query some how.

```
var name = "some name";
var fbId = "some fb Id";
var token = "some token";
var username = "some other username";
var password = "some other password";

var query = {
    fbId: fbId,
    token: token,
    "accounts.name":name
};
var update = {
    $set: {
         accounts: [{
            name: name,
            credentials: {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }
        }]
    }

};
var options = {
    upsert: true
};
User.update(query, update, options,
    function (err, numberAffected, rawResponse) {
        //handle it
    });
);
```

To sum up my question, is it reasonable to think I can update this with one call and if so how? Or should I find the object, replace its values and then reinsert it to the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `$` array update operator:

```
var query = {
    fbId: fbId,
    token: token,
    "accounts.name":name
};
var update = {
    $set: {
         "accounts.$": [{       //The $ operator goes into the update object
            name: name,
            credentials: {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/):

> The positional $ operator identifies an element in an array to update
>   without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the
>   array.

EDIT:

According to this [MongoDB JIRA page](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3326), using upsert with the $ positional operator is still an open issue.

I searched around and found a possible solution, which unfortunately defeats your aim of achieving this with one call. It can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23488436/2043580).

To summarize that answer, you will have to first send the update query without the `upsert` flag. Then check the response to see whether the document was updated, if not (this means such a subdocument does not exist), send another query with the `$push` operator to insert a new subdocument in the array.

Comment: Getting the following error response. The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: accounts.$

Comment: Oh, you need to set the upsert flag to true as well.

Comment: It was. When I comment out the upsert flag I get no errors but it also updates nothing.

Comment: the link you provided in your edit had a working answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If `$push` is working for you but you want to avoid adding duplicates to the array, then try `$addToSet`. It'll add a value to an array, as long as that value isn't already in it. Check out the [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) documentation.

**Update**

From your original post:

> I'm trying to update accounts each time the user adds a new one. So in
>   this case I can use $push just fine. But I don't want duplicate names,
>   and $push fails here.

```
var uniqueAccount = {
  name:'unique account',
  credentials: {
    username:'new username',
    password:'some secret password'
  }
};

db.accounts.update({fbId: fbId, token: token},
  {accounts: {$addToSet: uniqueAccount}});
```