# mongodb performance when updating/inserting subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo database used to represent spreadsheets with three collections representing respectively cell values (row, col, value), cell formatting (row, col, object representing the format) and cell sizes (whether it's a row or column size, its index and the size). 

Every document in all the collections also has a field to identify the table it refers to (containing the table's name) and I'm using upserts (mongoose's `findOneAndReplace` method with `upsert:true`) for all insertions/updates.

I was thinking of "pulling the schema inside out", by keeping a single collection representing the table and having the documents previously contained in the three collections as subdocuments inside it, as I thought it would make it more organized. 

However, reading up on the subject of subdocuments, it looks like in any case two queries would be needed for every insertion/update (eg, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470658/mongodb-upsert-sub-document)). Therefore, I was wondering if the changes I had in mind would lead to a hit on performance (I guess upserts still need to do a search and then either update or insert, so that would still be two queries behind the scenes, but there might be some optimization I'm not aware of) and in trying to simplify the schema I would not only complicate the insertion/update procedures but also get lower performances. Thanks!

Comment: Any answer would probably be primarily opinion-based . Anyway, one thing you should ask to yourself is _how_ you intend to use the data: What kind of queries will you send to the DB ?  Can you afford to hold the whole spreadsheet in RAM ? Is there a chance to reach the 16MB limit ? Is there concurrent updates of some cells ? Will you have "protected" cells ? Answering those questions (and many others) for _your_ application will help you to design _your_ schema.

Comment: Thank you, you raise some good points..especially regarding the type of queries. I'm expecting mostly write queries so I'll probably stick with what I already have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a performance hit. MongoDB has collection-level update locks. By keeping everything in a single collection you are ultimately limiting the number of concurrent update operations your application can perform, hence leading to decreased performance. The caveat to this, is that it totally dependant on how your application is doing the writes.

On the flip side is that you could potentially save on read operations as you'd need to query a single collection rather than 3. However, scaling reads is easy compared to writes, and writes are typically the bottleneck, so its kind of hard to say if that's worth it.