# How to insert or update the existing document in MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, nosql

How to insert new document in a `MongoDB` collection if there's no other document with specified unique field exists, or update the existing one otherwise?

Is there anything more reasonable than just using `findOne` and `save` methods with some conditions?

Comment: You could try the `upsert=true` option in the `collection.update()` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: upsert sub-document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470658/mongodb-upsert-sub-document)