# Mongoose : update nested document array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

my collection is as follows :

```
   "_id" : ObjectId("5751f7892ae95d601f40411d"),

   "doc" : [
    {
        "org" : ObjectId("5751f7892ae95d601f40411c"),
        "action" : 0,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5751f7892ae95d601f40411e")
    },
    {
        "org" : ObjectId("5751952cace204c507fad255"),
        "action" : 1,
        "_id" : ObjectId("575217ce341cf6512b8dff39")
    }     ]
```

I want to update action field in the doc with org:5751952cace204c507fad255
so action will equal 2 
I know this has already been answered many times  but it's not working for me

Here is what I tried  but Collection didn't change:

```
     Model.update(
    {
        "_id":ObjectId("5751f7892ae95d601f40411d"),
        "doc.org":ObjectId("5751952cace204c507fad255")
    },
    {
        "$inc": {
                "doc.$.action": 1
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Where are you getting the `ObjectId()` wrapper from?

Comment: var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;  I also thought it's a problem finding my collection but I tried Model.find with the same conditions and printed the result  and my collection was successfully  found

Comment: Have you tried updating without wrapping the string `_id`s?

Comment: Yes I tried both. I think my problem is not about the nested document , because I have just tried to update the name of my collection since it  has a field name  : db.Employee.update({_id:ObjectId("575194e6ace204c507fad250")},{FName:"youssef"}) ,  It says  WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 }) , but when I go to see my Employee collection  FName is not changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can try using positional operator `$` to increment matched action `doc.$.action`

like:

```
//assume you passed modelId and orgId in request body
// According to your tag you may used mongoose so use mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5751f7892ae95d601f40411d') instead of ObjectId("5751f7892ae95d601f40411d")
// or direct req.body.modelId without convert
Model.update(
    {
        "_id": req.body.modelId,
        "doc.org": req.body.orgId
    },
    {
        "$inc": {
                "doc.$.action": 1
        }
    },
    function(error, updatedData) {
        if(error) {
            return res.status(400).send(error);
        }
        return res.status(200).send(updatedData);
    }
);
```

Comment: Sorry I  just forgot to put the $ when I was writing my question , actually  even with doc.$.action, my collection didn't update

Comment: you can try using  `"_id": req.body.modelId` or `mongoose.Types.ObjectId("25...")` for both `_id` and `doc.org`

Comment: I tried both but to no avail,  I also tried in Mongo shell , when I add this to my query   { upsert: true } , I get error :  "errmsg" : "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: doc.$.action"

Comment: that means no document found according to your match condition.

Comment: if you want to update specific one document use `Model.findOneAndUpdate()`

Comment: I tried something simple  by trying to change a field named : "FName" : b.Employee.update({_id:ObjectId("575194e6ace204c507fad250")},{FName:"newFname"}) , It says WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 }) , but when I go to see my Employee collection FName is not changed

Comment: you may also get idea why you got this error message. from this link answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470658/mongodb-upsert-sub-document

Comment: should use `{$set: {FName:"newFname"}},{new: true}` where `new: true` will return updated document

Comment: db.Employee.update({_id:ObjectId("575194e6ace204c507fad250")},{$set:{FName:"youssef"}},{new: true})
-> WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
it's mached but not modified

Comment: Shaishab Roy , this is getting really weird ,  now I tried  FindOneAndUpdate like you said before,  and it returned my update document {
 "_id" : ObjectId("575194e6ace204c507fad250"),
 "FName" : "newName",
 "LName" : "youssef"
}
 but when I do Employee.find to make sure it's modified  , it still  got the old FName value

Comment: can you show me your server side function where you implemented this also model?

Comment: var org_permissionSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        org: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Organization'},
        action:Number
    }
);   var Employee= module.exports=mongoose.model('Employee',{   doc:[org_permissionSchema] });        | my updating code :  Employee.update(
        {"_id":req.body.emp_id,"doc.org":req.body.org},
        {$set:{"doc.$.action":55}}
    )

Comment: Hi shaishab roy , this worked  for me in mongo shell : db.employees.update({"_id":ObjectId("5756d0bcb9c2c7ae1c0e6e0f"),"doc.org":ObjectId("5756d0d2b9c2c7ae1c0e6e11")},{$set:{"doc.$.action":140}})                                                                
I tried the same code but it's not working on the server side with mongoose ,

Comment: Finally it's working , I just had to add a callback function  in the Employee.update(......,function(err,raw){}) , apparently this function was necessary to save my update even if I'm not using it