# MONGODB: updating a nested array in a subdocument

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mean-stack

I am able to update an array inside a document using $addToSet, but I want to update an array which is inside a document array.

## My Schema:

```
const mySchema1 = new Schema({
    myId : {type:String, unique:true},
    name : String,
    entries : [{
        value : String,
        keywords:[String]
    }]
});
```

## routes.js

```
app.put('/api/entity',function(req,res){
    let model = new Entity();
    console.log(req.body);
    model.collection.update({"myId":req.body.myId,"entries":req.body.entries},{$addToSet:{"entries":{$each:[req.body.entries]}}},function(err,entries){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }else{
            res.send(entries);
        }
    })
});
```

Now I want to update(if exists)/insert(if don't exist),
1. Value
2. keywords of a particular value

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470658/mongodb-upsert-sub-document this might be related to your question

Answer (score 0):

```
var entries = req.body.entries;
// match ALL of the documents whose `entires` attribute contains ALL `req.body.entries`
var query = {"myId":req.body.myId, "entries": {$all: entries}};

// match SOME of the documents whose `entires` attribute contains SOME `req.body.entries`
// var query = {"myId":req.body.myId, "entries": {$some: entries}};

// ADD all `req.body.entries` to the matched documents
var update = {$addToSet:{"entries":{$each:[entries]}};

// Create a new matching document if one doesn't already exeist
var options = {upsert = 1};


app.put('/api/entity',function(req,res){
    let model = new Entity();

    console.log(req.body);

    model.collection.update(
      query,
      update,
      options
    },function(err,entries){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }else{
            res.send(entries);
        }
    })
});
```

By the way, you can query your `Entity` db by using a simpler syntax. `Entity.update()`