# how to update in element array mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a exemple data:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5694ba11b3957b7ff69c4547"),
"name" : "Okas 1",
"job" : {
    "name" : "job try1",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ff9f7a336e3bba40a1d5c")
},
"categories" : {
    "ss" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "10",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ff9f7a336e3bba40a1d5c")
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "50",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ff9f7a336e3bba40a1d5f")
        }
    ]
}
```

if I update with new data .

```
[{
   "name" : "800",
   "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ff9f7a336e3bba40a1d5a")
},
{
   "name" : "8",
   "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ff9f7a336e3bba40a1d5f")
}]
```

I should get the data

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5694ba11b3957b7ff69c4547"),
"name" : "Okas 1",
"job" : {
    "name" : "job try1",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ff9f7a336e3bba40a1d5c")
},
"categories" : {
    "ss" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "10",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ff9f7a336e3bba40a1d5c")
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "8",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ff9f7a336e3bba40a1d5f")
        },    
        {
             "name" : "800",
             "_id" : ObjectId("5a6ff9f7a336e3bba40a1d5a")
        }
    ]
}
```

> So I want to update if data exeist just update value but if not exist
>   add new element in to array categories. I try but not working.  the
>   results are not appropriate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: upsert sub-document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470658/mongodb-upsert-sub-document)

Comment: sorry but I think this is different.

Comment: This is the same question. Please read the linked answers carefully.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
model.findOne({_id:req.params.id}, (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  if(!data) {
      var newData = new model({
        name: req.body.name
        .....
  })
      newData.save((err, newdata) => {
         // Response
       })
  } else {
      data.name = req.body.name
     data.save((err, data) => {
         // Response
       })
  }
```

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: It's simple, you are looking for items by `findOne` mongoose method, then if you don't find item with the ID you create new item...I was also confused, I'm still a beginner, try to understand the principle, then use mongodb/mongoose docs to write the code.