# MongoDB C# - Upsert an element in a list

Tags: c#, mongodb

Using the following:

```
class A
{
    ...
    List<B> L;
}

class B
{
    string Id;
    string S;
}
```

I am trying to do an upsert of a B object in A.L but with B.Id as the key.

Right now, if I do AddToSet in in update, I will get an extra object in the L array if any field in B is different than what is already there.

AddToSet will consider:

```
B: { Id: "3", S: "1" }
B: { Id: "3", S: "2" }
```

as two different objects

So, I can add A.L.Any(x => x.Id == "1") to the search and then do a set in the update, but this will work to replace an object, and not insert it if nothing is found.

I am trying to find how to make the upsert in an array in one call since it needs to be atomic on my end.

How can I do that?

---

Clarification:

If I have the following data:

```
{
    L :
    [
        { Id: "1", S: "A" }
    ]
}
```

and I want to upsert: { Id: "2", S: "B" }

I would like the result to be:

```
{
    L :
    [
        { Id: "1", S: "A" },
        { Id: "2", S: "B" }
    ]
}
```

and then if I upsert: { Id: "2", S: "C" }
I would like the output to be:

```
{
    L :
    [
        { Id: "1", S: "A" },
        { Id: "2", S: "C" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please support your post with sample json documents. What is your input and how you want to see your document?

Comment: I added an example

Comment: @Thomas have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470658/mongodb-upsert-sub-document ?

Comment: Yes, I saw it but I'm looking for an atomic solution since it's to update data based on REST requests.