# Increment or insert mongo nested array values

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoid

I have a collection with such documents stuct:

```
{ 
  id: 1, 
  my_field: [
    { 
      date: date1, 
      type: A,
      value: 1
    }, 
    { 
      date: dateX, 
      type: X, 
      value: Z
    }, 
    ...
  ]
```

What the problem i solve: 
I have id, date, type and value. I have to find document by id(which is always present), then element in `my_field` by `date` and `type` and increment value. If this element doesnt present in `my_field` i have to insert it(struct to `my_field`). And i look for the most efficient way

I will be very thankful for ideas!

Mongo 4.2

Also it will be great if someone helps with to write this on ruby-driver for mongo :)

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a similar post: [mongoose update array or add to the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61234012/mongoose-update-array-or-add-to-the-array).

Answer (score 0):

Use find-and-modify and $push.

- https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-crud-operations/#updating
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/