# why mongoose does not have regular array methods

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

Im new to mongoose and i have an array in my schema that is a nested document like the following:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String
    friends: [friendsSchema],
});

const friendsSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, unique: true },
});
```

lets say i want to add a friend to a specefic user, i need to do the following:

- check if the user id is valid or not
- check if the user id exists in the database or not
- if the user exists check if he already have a friend that goes by that name
- if he does not push into the array of friends a new friend

I initially believed that once I obtained the user, I could simply execute a foreach loop on the user.friends array to verify the friend's existence. However, it turns out that [mongoose Arrays](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/array.html#) behave differently from regular JavaScript arrays. This was quite frustrating because it meant I would need to construct a complex query, potentially resulting in additional database reads, instead of directly accessing the user and checking the desired information from the user object. Consequently, I came up with the following implementation:

```
    let { name, userId } = req.body;
    try {
        //check if userId is a valid mongoose objectId
        if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(userId)) {
            res.status(404).json({ error: "invalid user id" });
        }
        // get the user
        let user = await userModel.findById(userId);
        if (!user) {
            res.status(404).json({ error: "user not found" });
        }
        
        let user = user.friends.foreach(friend =>{ 
                   if (friend.name === name)
                      {     
                        res.status(404).json({error: "friend already added to user"});
                      }
        }); 
        
        user.friends.push({ name});
        user.save();
        res.status(200).json(user);
```

- is it possible to do all those previous steps in one single query, like one database read that does everything?
- what was the rational of having a distinct Array type on mongoose?

PS: this is not a duplicate question of how to push and save to an array

Comment: I believe reading through [MongoDB: upsert sub-document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470658/mongodb-upsert-sub-document) will help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to find the user and loop through of their friends. You can just do a conditional update and push the friend to the array if the condition is not met. For example:

Delete from here and everything after it:

```
let user = await userModel.findById(userId);
```

Change to this:

```
const user = await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
   {
      _id: userId, //< Find a user with this id
      'friends.name': { $ne: name } //< But also can't have a friend already with this name 
   },
   {
      $push: { // If you find a user with that id and no existing friend then push
         "friends": {name: name}
      }
   },
   { new: true } //< This tells mongoose to give you back the user with the friend added i.e the updated version
);
if (!user) {
   res.status(404).json({ error: "user not found or friend already added" });
} else{
   res.status(200).json(user);
}
```

If you really wanted to, you could still first check to see if the user existed with a quick:

```
const existingUser = await userModel.findById(userId);
```

Then based on the return value do the conditional update but your application really shouldn't be allowing your users to try and update a user that doesn't exist.